# How to cut a mesh to fit into a hole in another mesh?

Tags: modeling

I'm kind of a blender noob and need some help.  The picture below sort of sums up the problem.  I have a pair of black glasses which I did not model.  I also have some "lens models" that are 8cm in diameter and modeled to the exact shape of a specific eyeglasses prescription.

The image below is an exaggerated solution, some of the prescription lenses are a bit thicker than the frames, but not this much.

The obvious solution was to select a loop of vertices on the glasses and extrude them out into a mesh I can boolen with the prescription lens to cut it to size.  This didn't work because selecting loops on these glasses didn't seem to work. So how to do it?

The prescription lenses are actually like real glasses lenses, I have to use them to get correct refraction when this is ray/path traced, so I need a way to cut them to fit the frames.

The model for these glasses is available here.  It already has some lenses in the frames but not all models I want to use do, some are empty.

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/glasses-4b8a1e54f3084c63828fe8c324198aec

[image]

Comment: You say that "selecting loops on these glasses didn't seem to work", maybe you should share your file so that we can try, you should be able to select the frame and use it as boolean object

Comment: Hi, at the very end of my post there is a link to the model on sketchfab.  I have tried other models too and have the same problem with all of them.  By the way, the way I got the white shape above was by extruding one of the lenses in the glasses.  Doesn't work for everything though because some eyeglasses models have no lenses or have ones with odd topology.   I'm still a blender noob so maybe I'm not doing it right.

Comment: If it's a copyright free model, could you please share it on https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform?

Comment: The model is ccattribution.  Are you unable to download it from the sketchfab link?

Comment: Yes I need to register, if it's creative commons please share it

Comment: Here it is, I had to convert it from the original USDZ which it would not let me post. 
 Every time I import the file I have to scale it 0.001 or it comes out gigantic, but that's a different problem.[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=4D5D2aEk" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/4D5D2aEk/)

Comment: If you select all in Edit mode and press Alt J it will untriangulate the frame and you'll be able to select the edge loop of the frame, then use it as a boolean object. That said it looks like the glass is already correctly cut off, no?

Comment: As I said, this model has lenses, others don't.  Either way I need to take one of my prescription lens models and cut it to fit into the frame.  I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Yes Alt J works here

Comment: Took me a bit to test this, but it works....Thank you!

Comment: OK, fine then......   ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> it will untriangulate the frame and you'll be able to select the edge loop of the frame, then use it as a boolean object.